# I need to split the values within a cell of google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a similar type of data inside a Google Sheet Column,

**0000 Place Court NE, Atlanta, GA 30000**

The Data in all the cells of this column is in the same format.

The only data I need is "Atlanta, GA"

Is can anyone provide a custom formula to split the value I need from the cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.
`^*?,([^*]*)\D.*`

if the cell is A1 then formula will be like
`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^*?,([^*]*)\D.*")`

Answer (score 0):

Slightly shorter:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,",(.+\s)\d")
```

and wrap in TRIM if desired.

After the first comma take everything up to the space preceeding a number.